# Best Practice for Serializing an XML Document from a Class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

The current solution that I have is working fine. I have a C# class `Person` which I am serializing into an XML document using the `XmlSerializer` object.  I know that the following class structure will be Serialized into the XML document (also below).

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("recordId")]
    public int recordId { get; set; }
}
```

... will be Serialized into the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person recordId="1">
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  <Age>32</Age>
</Person>
```

Assume each property has the sameShould I explicitly preface each element appropriately with `XmlElement` tag as I have with the `XmlAttribute`; or is leaving the `Person` class as defined above perfectly fine and acceptable?

What are the implications for doing so or not doing so?

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("recordId")]
    public int recordId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only up-side to this is if you ever rename the properties or class (bad), you can specify the mapped element name without changing your code. But being a good programmer, you wouldn't change property names anyway. I don't see any need to specify the element/name if the default names work fine.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for your input. That's was kind of the general feeling that I had as well. If you want to make it an answer, I can mark it as such.  There were a couple of instances in my code where I had to include the `XmlElement` tag to explicitly define a `List<T>` and in including the tag, it eliminated a duplicate tag from my XML document.

Comment: I have a different opinion.  Programmers should always declare every variable where possible.  So declaring the XML tags and attributes should fall under same requirements.  I know in many cases Linq doesn't allow proper declarations and using "var" will work but in my opinion a bad alternative.   I avoid the "var" declaration except if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `XmlSerializer` uses the property name for the XML element name and 99% of the time this works. The edge cases are where you need to have a custom element name mapped to a property name (for example, you are making the code model from the XML and the XML element begins with an invalid character).

Explicitly decorating them, to me, is just code bloat. If the default names are correct then let the `XmlSerializer` do its default actions with the names. There are very few (frowned upon) cases where explicitly decorating the name would let you change the underlying property name without breaking serialization, but if you had to do that then you can add the attribute at that time.

So for what its worth, I'd leave them off as long as the results are appropriate and only add them to signify that something is different with that particular property. For example, you gave the code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("recordId")]
    public int recordId { get; set; }
}
```

Which immediately draws the eye to `recordId` as being different. If you have the attributes explicitly set on all the items, it is less apparent that it has to be serialized differently.

Comment: I believe readability goes a long way in programming.  The less clutter and bloat, the easier it is to understand what you're looking at.

Comment: Well said, Ron Beyer.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlRoot` attribute would allow you to control the name of the element without changing the name of the class.

If the class name is the same as the XML element name then there is no need to include it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The class name is the same as the `<root>` element, and the property names are the same as the elements under the root.  I didn't see any clear way of defining an attribute without the `XmlAttribute` tag, and I had to use the `XmlElement` tag to remove some parent elements which were created in error according to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it doesn't matter how to deal with it. But, as for me, it looks more readable when I have explicit XML serialization contract - an appropriate type for serializing without attributes. However, sometimes XML document requires elements with a names that are not suitable with a C# lang. naming specification and you have to use attributes :)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Purely for discussion purposes, when you reference "... names that are not suitable with a C# lang ..." are you referring to reserved keywords?  Wouldn't using those as properties be bad programming practice anyway?  Do you have any examples of this case?

Comment: @Russ Sometimes you might need to serialize 'Age' property as 'age', so you can name property 'age', but that's inconsistent with C# naming standarts (properties should be named with a capital letter)

Comment: @Dimitry That makes perfect sense, thank you.  I guess I even made that mistake in the example I gave with the property `recordId`; the property should have been named `RecordID`, having the `XmlAttribute` defined as-is.